# Can I show `augmented comment` for existing code (src or bin) in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a third party .jar file used frequently in my appliction. But I have no **original** document and/or source code. I wrote a seperate document to explain this library.

It is somewhat inconvenient. Can I get better experience in IDEA by

1. Given my own doc comment, IDEA dispaly my `augmented comment` for this library.
2. Given my understood nice variable name, IDEA show my nice name in decompiled source code.

Comment: What do you mean by "my own document"? If you have source code for the compiler jar you can add it in [library configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-library-dialog.html) dialog, then IDE will take parameter names, javadoc from that source.

Comment: I do not have soure code. I wrote my own document for this library.